# aws cloudformation, what does the following mean

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have inherited an aws project with the following cloudformation settings for a vpc security group.

```
SecurityGroupEgress:
  - IpProtocol: -1
    FromPort: -1
    ToPort: -1
    CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I am not an expert in networking or VPC, could someone explain to me what the following means, specifically the -1.

Answer (score 1):

It means:

- On whatever security group this configuration is attached
- Allow all traffic
- On any port
- From anywhere in the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)

From [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-security-group-egress.html):

> You can use `-1` for the type or code to mean all types or all codes.